# Создание dblink к БД MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Необходимо создать dblink к БД Mysql.
Просьба помочь.

Ошибка при выборе из dblink

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-28500: connection from ORACLE to a non-Oracle system returned this message:
ORA-02063: preceding line from TEST2
```

Конфиг odbc.ini
cat /etc/odbc.ini

```
[MySQL]
Driver      = MySQL
Description = MySQL
Database  = ocsweb
Server      = 10.167.0.14
User = ospo
Password = qwerty11
PORT = 3306
```

Конфиг из hs/admin

cat /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/hs/admin/initdg4odbc.ora

```
HS_FDS_CONNECT_INFO = ospo
HS_FDS_SHAREABLE_NAME = /usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so
set ODBCINI=/etc/odbc.ini
```

Конфиг listener.ora

cat /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/network/admin/listener.ora

```
DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = XEPDB1

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = oracleapex)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
 (SID_LIST =
  (SID_DESC =
   (ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE)
   (SID_NAME = MySQL)
   (PROGRAM = dg4odbc)
   #(ENVS ="LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/bin/dg4odbc:/opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/lib")
  )
 )
```

Тут насчет ENVS не совсем уверен, поэтому закомментировал.

Конфиг tnsnames.ora

cat /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/network/admin/tnsnames.ora

```
MYSQL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
     (SID = mysql)
    )
    (HS = OK)
  )
```

Тестирую odbc

```
isql -v MySQL
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
```

Тест tnsping

```
tnsping mysql

TNS Ping Utility for Linux: Version 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on 02-JUL-2019 10:12:13

Copyright (c) 1997, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
/opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/network/admin/sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = mysql)) (HS = OK))
OK (40 msec)
```

Захожу в БД

```
sqlplus sys/ as sysdba
```

Создаю дблинк

```
SQL> create public database link test2 connect to "ospo" identified by "qwerty11" using 'MYSQL';
Database link created.
```

Пытаюсь выбрать данные

```
select * from "ports"@test2
                      *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-28500: connection from ORACLE to a non-Oracle system returned this message:
ORA-02063: preceding line from TEST2
```

В интернете везде пишут что такая ошибка когда пишешь логин и пароль без двойных кавычек, т.к. oracle автоматом подставляет большие буквы для логина и пароля. Ну тут я делаю с кавычками.

Где еще мог ошибиться? пожалуйста помогите :)

Comment: Доброго вечера. Неужели никто не создавал дблинки с oracle на mysql?
Может хоть конфиги у кого остались?